# How 3D earth rotate own axis in android opengl?

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, rotation

I am developing a very simple 3D earth system by the android opengl. 
every one knows that Earth is actually rotating on an axis known as its rotational axis. The Earth's axis is actually tilted by 23.5' vertically like the image: http://www.tutordynamic.com/science/earths-rotation.htm.  I could rotate the earth around the x, y,z axis by the glRotatef(32,0,0,1). but how to rotate the earth around his own axis(23.5) not x ,y, z axis. Could your give me some hints, codes or webiste links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need both the continuous rotation of earth on its own axis and vertically tilted earth by 23.5 (angle). For continuous rotation you need timer to change the angle of rotation and another rotation for tilted earth. So,at first rotate the earth about x-axis with continuously changing angle of rotation  and second time rotated the earth by angle 23.5 about z-axis.

Sample pseudo code:

```
glRotate3f(23.5,0,0,1); //rotaion about z-axis
glRotate3f(_angle,1,0,0);  //"_angle" is changing variable for continuous rotation of earth about x_axis
drawEarth(); // draw the earth
```

Comment: Hi Dinesh, You know the earth revolves around the sun. there are three rotation, firstly, the glRotate3f(23.5,0,0,1); //rotaion about z-axis, lRotate3f(_angle,1,0,0);  //"_angle" is changing variable for continuous rotation of, then revolves around the sun. my code is the following:

Comment: :gl.glPushMatrix();angle+=orbitalIncrement; //8gl.glRotatef(-23.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
gl.glRotatef(angle, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);  gl.glPushMatrix();
  gl.glTranslatef(mPlanet.m_Pos[0], mPlanet.m_Pos[1], mPlanet.m_Pos[2]);//Combined 17-18
  //gl.glRotatef(-23.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); 
  gl.glRotatef(day, 0, 1, 0);
  mPlanet.draw(gl);      //19
     gl.glPopMatrix();
     day += 1;gl.glPopMatrix();

Comment: You are correct three rotation needed.